# LINQ : Group by getting object and its count

Tags: c#, linq

My question is: I got a lot of data in everyday (100+) with a date parameter. I will use it in fullcalendar.

My query is:

```
var list = _cService.GetListAll(Id)
                    .Where(x => x.StartDate.Date == model.Start.Date)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.StartDate.Date)
                    .ToList();
```

This returns data as shown here, but also these dates are not distinct. We got 80+ for each day. Value is count for that date:

[image]

This is as expected. But I need data like this - is there any way to make it as shown here?

[image]

Comment: You didn't post any EF Core or ASP.NET Core code. If `GetListAll()` returns a `List<T>`, this is a local grouping operation

Comment: Sounds like you just need to project your output after the `GroupBy` with something like `.Select(g => new { Date = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })` but it's impossible to tell for sure as you haven't given enough detail.

Comment: Even so, you don't calculate the count anywhere. If you wanted to get the date and count you should use `.Select(grp=>new {Date=grp.Key,Count=grp.Count()});`. All EF Core `GroupBy` examples have a `Select` call that specifies the aggregates to return

Comment: I see so I gotta select after group by.  .Select(grp=>new {Date=grp.Key,Count=grp.Count()});  this query means i dont understand I change it like this but now it gives error { Date = grp.StartDate, Count = grp.StartDate.Count() }

Comment: But the problem is I can't get count

Comment: Please read the comments again. You are not giving us enough information so we cannot help. You get an error? OK but *what is the error?* What output do you need? Please spend some time on your question.

Comment: What output do you need? is the second image, I'm triyng your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way :

```
var list = _cService.GetListAll(Id)
                    .Where(x => x.StartDate.Date == model.Start.Date)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.StartDate.Date)
                    .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                    .ToList();
```

And then access one item of the list this way for example :

```
DateTime key = list[0].Key;
int count = list[0].Count;
```

Comment: Yes as mentioned above group by date.date then select key with count works fine. Thank all of you